# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Starting from this jQuery code:

```
var country_name_list=document.getElementById("country");            
$.post(getcountry,function (data) {
    var Rcountry_name_list=JSON.parse(data);
    var arr=[];
    for(var i=0;i<Rcountry_name_list.countries.length;i++){
         var r_id=Rcountry_name_list.countries[i].country_id;
         var r_name= Rcountry_name_list.countries[i].country_name;
         var option_name = document.createElement("option");
         option_name.textContent =r_name;
         option_name.value = r_id;

         country_name_list.append(option_name);     
     }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="rform" novalidate="novalidate">
    <label class="control-label">Country </label>
    <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control" >
        <option value=" " disabled selected hidden>Select Country</option>
        <option value="0"></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

On the line `country_name_list.append(option_name);` I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null in jQuery

Comment: Can you show the json response?

Comment: Since you post nothing, why don't you use $.get ?

Comment: @TonySamperi Where's the connection to the problem that `country_name_list` is `null`?

Comment: There's no connection, but I think this place is meant to learn something and improve code when possible.

Comment: @Tony sir I use getcountry web services.

Comment: what is the error, your question is very unclair. you should consider adding some ifnormations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when a DOM selector returns null, it means the element was not found. So you have to wait for the DOM to be loaded.

With jQuery it's enough to wrap your selector in the following statement

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

vi5ion's right, but you could also improve your code

```
var country_name_list = document.getElementById("country");
```

> Here you didn't use jQuery, so you have to keep using javascript DOM methods.

```
$.get(getcountry, function (data) {
```

> Here $.get is enough

```
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
```

> I think Capital letter is only for classes

```
    var option, current;
```

> If you create the variables here, you avoid creating a new variable for each loop, so will save time!

```
    var list = response.countries;
    for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
        current = list.countries[i];
        option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = current.country_name;
        option.value = current.country_id;
        country_name_list.appendChild(option_name);
```

> As vi5ion suggests *appendChild()* is what you need

```
     }

});
```

It seems easier to read the code now, didn't it?
Hope this is useful!

Answer (score 0):

`country_name_list` is not a jQuery object and therefore doesn't have the `append()` function.

In fact, most of your code is plain JavaScript and not jQuery, so you would probably want to use the function `appendChild()` instead.

**Edit: added alternative jQuery solution below**

If you insist on using jQuery you could wrap your variable.
That can either be done here

```
var country_name_list = $('#country');
```

or here

```
$(country_name_list).append(option_name);
```

but not both.

Comment: Depending on the browser there is also a "native" `.append()` method available: [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) / http://caniuse.com/#feat=dom-manip-convenience

Comment: Oh I didn't actually know that. The lack of support in IE would be a dealbreaker for most people though.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive an error of type "Cannot read property XXX of null", you want to make sure that your element exists when your script is called.

For instance, you would place your javascript right before the closing  tag to make sure that the element has is in the DOM.

Alternatively, if you have your script inserted in the header, or prior in the page, you may want to enclose i inside the $.ready() method to ensure that it is only run after the DOM is ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ... your code
}
```

You can find more information at: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, I did try the above solutions, but mine was due to different reason.

Therefore, one solution would be wrapping it under the document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

One another solution will be, try using jQuery() instead of $(), this was helpful for me.

```
jQuery('#item_field').append('<div></div>');
```

instead of

```
$('#item_field').append('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error
I tried entering the script tag in the body section
It worked for me